# Partial implicit differentiation exercise - where was my mistake?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm trying to find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ for the following:

$$xyz^3+\ln(xyz)=0$$

My work is as follows:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[xyz^3+\ln(xyz)]=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[0]$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[xyz^3] = 3x^3y+z^3y$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[\ln(xyz)] = \frac{1}{xyz} (xy\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + yz)$$

$$\therefore\ (3x^3y+z^3y) + (\frac{1}{xyz} (xy\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + yz)) = 0$$

$$xyz(-3x^3y-z^3y) = xy\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} +yz$$

Finally,

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{-z(3x^4y+z^3xy+1)}{x}$$

If you did me the honor of trying to follow this mess, which I hopefully (though could've) didn't screw up, allow me to bring up the issue, in the form of a seemingly different answer from my lecturer:

[image]

This seems to mean I'm wrong. But I'm not exactly sure where. Could someone spot my mistake?

Comment: Your partial differentiation of $xyz^3$ above seems  incorrect. It should contain the partial $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one mistake:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(xyz^3)=yz^3 + 3xyz^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}. $$

Comment: Ahh, I see. Is this a viable approach, though? As it differs from that of my lecturer's but it's more intuitive to me.

Comment: For these types of problems, yes. Your approach, along with the correct derivative I show above, gives the exact same answer as your lecturer gives.